# What json schema needed for this style?

Tags: android, json, material-design, android-recyclerview

I have this layout (with statically data ) :

[image]

This is horizontal recycler view in the vertical recycler view , I populate this recycler view with fake data , But i should tell to web programmer json schema for this work .

> This is my Horizontal recycler view adapters :

```
public class HorizontalRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItemModelha;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== constructor  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public HorizontalRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItemModelha) {
        this.context = context;
        this.singleItemModelha = singleItemModelha;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== View holder class  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView txtTitle;
        private ImageView imgItem;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            imgItem = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You are clicked at : " + txtTitle.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== on create view holder  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item_card,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== on bind view holder  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(singleItemModelha.get(position).getName());

        //glide
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== get item count  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(singleItemModelha != null){
            return singleItemModelha.size();
        }else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

> And This is Vertical recycler Adapter :

```
public class VerticalRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VerticalRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ListRowDataModel> listRowDataModelha;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== Constructor  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public VerticalRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListRowDataModel> listRowDataModelha) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listRowDataModelha = listRowDataModelha;
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== View Holder class  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView txtTitle;
        private Button btnMore;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            btnMore =(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMore);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_horizontal);
        }
    }



    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== on create view holder  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== on bind view holder  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(listRowDataModelha.get(position).getSectionTitle());
        holder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked at block : " + listRowDataModelha.get(position).getSectionTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(new HorizontalRecyclerAdapter(context,listRowDataModelha.get(position).getSingleItemModelha()));
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== get item count  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(listRowDataModelha != null){
            return listRowDataModelha.size();
        }else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

> And this is Recycler view activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<ListRowDataModel> allSampleData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_main);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

        allSampleData = new ArrayList<ListRowDataModel>();
        createDummyData();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(new VerticalRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this,allSampleData));

    }

    private void createDummyData() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            ListRowDataModel dm = new ListRowDataModel();

            dm.setSectionTitle("Section " + i);

            ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItemModel>();
            for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
                singleItem.add(new SingleItemModel("Item " + j, "URL " + j));
            }

            dm.setSingleItemModelha(singleItem);

            allSampleData.add(dm);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to all <3

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON structure should be an array of arrays.

Where each array (section) will contain multiple objects (items).

Something like this:

```
[
    [{}, {}],
    [{}, {}]
]
```

Comment: can you explain in detail ?